# Animated audio play button on iPhone

Tags: ios, media-player, playback, jplayer

I am playing audio in my app through FMOD. In my media player I currently just have a play button with a slider that tracks your progress through the audio clip. What I want to do is have basically a slider that wraps around the play button, showing the progress there.

For example, the play button in jplayer: http://www.jplayer.org/

I have looked around but have not found any libraries out there or any tutorials on how to implement this in Objective-C.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pages you might find useful.

- [Intro to Quartz](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/) - explains the basics of drawing with Quartz
- [Drawing Pie Charts](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/04/drawing-pie-charts.html) - explains how to draw arcs of circles
- [Advanced Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/AdvancedDrawing/AdvancedDrawing.html) - for making it look pretty

Basically, using these tutorials, you should be able to draw the arc of a circle behind your play button, which extends outside the button itself.  The angle of the arc should be the percentage of the progress through the audio file as a float (i.e. 0.0 to 1.0), multiplied by 360 degrees.

Do keep in mind the user interface implications of this design.  Having a circular progress bar will make it very difficult for the user to seek to different parts of the audio file, if that's a feature you support.

Comment: I figured this is what I was going to have to do, thanks for the links! I'm gonna take a crack at it.